# C# not existing element in ConcurrentDictionary causes BSOD in Release Compiled VErsion

Tags: c#

I have this step:

```
        StepInfo[(int)this.currentState].Tasks[0].Start();
```

This runs in an async task, when I run this piece of code in Debug mode; the compiler gives me the exception that the key is not present. However when this is compiled (ASP.NET/C#) to release it results in a BSOD. Apart from the missing null check I dont quite understand how to handle errors like this as the BSOD does not give me any information in production systems.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do a TryGetValue() with the key first? If the key doesn't exist then handle it more gracefully. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-6.0

Comment: I'm modifying that code right now; the code isnt very pretty; im just suprised why it does BSOD on me in production though.

Comment: a BSOD for a KeyNotFoundException is worthy of a bug report. Would be good if you could isolate and reproduce it in a smaller project under the same build settings.